# How to maintain two same type of form in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have two forms which fields are same but has different formControl names and validations and go to backend like that. Now, there are two forms with exactly the same codes but different form and formControl names and validations. Can I do this without code repeating like using ng-content or something like that?

[image: The debit from]
[image: The credit form]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with FormArray

Refer below links

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Answer (score 0):

create a component and add the form in it and you can reuse them by giving the selector in the tab content for both the credit and debit transaction tabs

```
<app-form><app-form>
```

By this way you can reuse the same form or else you can create a two form group in the same form

```
public transaction: FormGroup;

this.transaction = this.fb.group({
  CreditTransaction: this.createControls(),
  DebitTransaction: this.createControls()
})

 createControls(){
 return this.fb.group({
    // your controls
  })
 }
```

since you are using the same controls you can invoke a common function and return the controls from that function